# Delete a found file in C:\

Tags: c++

I have this C++ source to find `*.do` files in `c:\`.

My problem is, instead of showing them, I want to delete them.

How can I delete all `*.do` files in `c:\`?  My code only shows the directory path, I want to delete instead.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void GetFileListing(std::string directory, std::string fileFilter, bool recursively = true)
{
  if (recursively)
    GetFileListing(directory, fileFilter, false);

  directory += "\\";

  WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
  HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

  std::string filter = directory + (recursively ? "*" : fileFilter);

  hFind = FindFirstFile(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);

  if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    if (!recursively)
    {
      std::cout << directory + std::string(FindFileData.cFileName) << std::endl;
    }

    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
    {
      if (!recursively)
      {
        std::cout << directory + std::string(FindFileData.cFileName) << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
        if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)>0 && FindFileData.cFileName[0]!='.')
        {
          GetFileListing(directory + std::string(FindFileData.cFileName), fileFilter);
        }
      }
    }

    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);
    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
      std::cout << "FindNextFile error. Error is "<< dwError << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  GetFileListing("c:\\", "*.do");
}
```

Comment: C != C++. Your question is about one or the other. They're not the same language, and the tags are not synonyms. Tags are relevant here - use **only** the tags that are actually applicable to your question.

Comment: His question is about C++.  "C" in the topic is a disk, not a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`DeleteFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx), eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib");    

void GetFolderListing(std::string directory, const std::string &fileFilter, std::vector<std::string> *subfolders, std::vector<std::string> *files)
{    
    if (!directory.empty() && (*directory.rbegin() != '\\'))
        directory += "\\";

    std::string filter = directory;
    if (subfolders)
        filter += "*";
    else
        filter += fileFilter;

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    DWORD dwError;

    hFind = FindFirstFileA(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            std::cout << "FindFirstFile error " << dwError << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if ((subfolders) &&
                (lstrcmpA(FindFileData.cFileName, ".") != 0) &&
                (lstrcmpA(FindFileData.cFileName, "..") != 0))
            {
                subfolders->push_back(directory + FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((files) &&
                ((!subfolders) || PathMatchSpecA(FindFileData.cFileName, fileFilter.c_str())))
            {
                files->push_back(directory + FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &FindFileData));

    dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);
    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        std::cout << "FindNextFile error " << dwError << std::endl;
}

void DeleteFiles(const std::string &directory, const std::string &fileFilter, bool recursively = true)
{    
    std::vector<std::string> folders;
    std::vector<std::string> files;

    GetFolderListing(directory, fileFilter, (recursively) ? &folders : NULL, &files);

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = files.begin(); iter != files.end(); ++iter)
        DeleteFileA(iter->c_str());

    if (recursively)
    {
        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = folders.begin(); iter != folders.end(); ++iter)
            DeleteFiles(*iter, fileFilter, true);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DeleteFiles("c:\\", "*.do");
}
```

Or, using Unicode (which you should be using instead of ANSI):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib");    

void GetFolderListing(std::wstring directory, const std::wstring &fileFilter, std::vector<std::wstring> *subfolders, std::vector<std::wstring> *files)
{    
    if (!directory.empty() && (*directory.rbegin() != L'\\'))
        directory += L"\\";

    std::wstring filter = directory;
    if (subfolders)
        filter += L"*";
    else
        filter += fileFilter;

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    DWORD dwError;

    hFind = FindFirstFileW(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            std::cout << "FindFirstFile error " << dwError << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if ((subfolders) &&
                (lstrcmpW(FindFileData.cFileName, L".") != 0) &&
                (lstrcmpW(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") != 0))
            {
                subfolders->push_back(directory + FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((files) &&
                ((!subfolders) || PathMatchSpecW(FindFileData.cFileName, fileFilter.c_str())))
            {
                files->push_back(directory + FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &FindFileData));

    dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);
    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        std::cout << "FindNextFile error " << dwError << std::endl;
}

void DeleteFiles(const std::wstring &directory, const std::wstring &fileFilter, bool recursively = true)
{    
    std::vector<std::wstring> folders;
    std::vector<std::wstring> files;

    GetFolderListing(directory, fileFilter, (recursively) ? &folders : NULL, &files);

    for (std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = files.begin(); iter != files.end(); ++iter)
        DeleteFileW(iter->c_str());

    if (recursively)
    {
        for (std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = folders.begin(); iter != folders.end(); ++iter)
            DeleteFiles(*iter, fileFilter, true);
    }
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    DeleteFiles(L"c:\\", L"*.do");
}
```

Comment: oh, it seems amazing! but give me some erros: line 21 'cout' is not a member of 'std'
line 21 'endl' is not a member of 'std'
line 45 expected ')' before 'continue'
line 57 'cout' is not a member of 'std'
line 57 'endl' is not a member of 'std'
line 64 name lookup of 'iter' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

Comment: The `std` errors were because I had originally removed the `std::cout` calls and then removed `#include <iostream>`, and then later re-added `std::cout` but forgot to re-add `#include <iostream>` as well. I have fixed that.

Comment: thank you! now it shows me just one error: (.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `_imp__PathMatchSpecA@8' what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RickJoe: that should have been handled by the `#pragma`. Maybe your compiler's copy of `shlwapi.lib` does not include a reference to `PathMatchSpecA()`.  You really shouldn't be using the Ansi APIs anyway (I only did that because you are using `std::string`), you should be using the Unicode APIs instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I remove the `PathMatchSpecW` and compliled it. but the file went a little crazy deleting all files in all folders. it works, pretty dangerous tho.

Comment: Calling `FindFirstFile()` with a filter of `<folder>\*` matches everything in `<folder>`, so you have to compare file extensions manually. [`PathMatchSpec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727.aspx) handles that for you: "*Searches a string using a Microsoft MS-DOS wildcard match type.*" If you cannot make `PathMatchSpec()` work, you will have to find another pattern matching function to use, maybe from a Regular Expression library, or else write your own comparison code that extracts the file extension from `cFileName` and compares it to `fileFilter` manually.

Answer (score 2):

Make some [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (probably a `std::list<std::string>`, perhaps a `std::set<std::string>` or a `std::vector<std::string>`) containing the collections of found (absolute) file paths, then delete all of them (using [std::filesystem::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) or simply the C [remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) ...)

So you have two steps: first, you iterate on your file system to find relevant files (on Linux, I would use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) for that; perhaps your OS has something similar) without removing them (but collecting their *full* file path in the container). Second, you iterate on the container to remove every file path there.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you give me an example, is something like this? `std::remove << directory + std::string(FindFileData.cFileName) << std::endl;`

Comment: No, build the complete absolute file path, and add it to the container, and repeat with the next found file.